# Library to create standard html for sending email

Tags: .net, html-email

Is there any library out there in .NET that creates standard-compliant html (understood by most of email readers like outlook, gmail, hotmail etc.) from the html generated by rich textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one I've used is the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), but to convert RTF to HTML you'll need something else or in addition (google "RTF to HTML", some .NET-related results come up).